# How to convert Varchar to Int in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

How to convert Varchar to Int in sql server 2008.

i have following code when i tried to run it wont allowed me to convert Varchar to Int.

```
Select Cast([Column1] as INT)
```

Column1 is of Varchar(21) NOT NULL type and i wanted to convert it into Int.
actually i am trying to insert Column1 into another table having Field as INT.
can someone please help me to convert this ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Spaces will not be a problem for `cast`, however characters like `TAB`, `CR` or `LF` will appear as spaces, will not be trimmed by `LTRIM` or `RTRIM`, and will be a problem.

For example try the following:

```
declare @v1 varchar(21) = '66',
        @v2 varchar(21) = '   66   ',
        @v3 varchar(21) = '66' + char(13) + char(10),
        @v4 varchar(21) = char(9) + '66'

select cast(@v1 as int)   -- ok
select cast(@v2 as int)   -- ok
select cast(@v3 as int)   -- error
select cast(@v4 as int)   -- error
```

Check your input for these characters and if you find them, use `REPLACE` to clean up your data.

---

Per your comment, you can use [`REPLACE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) as part of your `cast`:

```
select cast(replace(replace(@v3, char(13), ''), char(10), '') as int)
```

If this is something that will be happening often, it would be better to clean up the data and modify the way the table is populated to remove the `CR` and `LF` before it is entered.

Comment: yes you are right at '@v3' is the same condition with my scenario is there any way or solution over it so that we can convert it from varchar to int ?

Comment: @VikrantMore, updated my answer to include the use of `REPLACE` to remove the `CRLF`.

Answer (score 10):

you can use convert function :

```
Select convert(int,[Column1])
```

Answer (score 2):

That is how you would do it, is it throwing an error?  Are you sure the value you are trying to convert is convertible?  For obvious reasons you cannot convert `abc123` to an int.

**UPDATE**

Based on your comments I would remove any spaces that are in the values you are trying to convert.

Comment: @AbeMiessler yes my values in that columns are 66 or 2 there is no single characters but there was an Left Trailing Blank Spaces only.

Comment: What error is it throwing?  Are you sure there are no spaces in there?

Comment: Are there any NULL Values possibly?

Comment: but are all the values in the column in the table ints? Depending on where the conversion is in the query it might be trying to convert values that won't end up in the final result set. Please post the actual query not just the snippet.

Comment: @AbeMiessler there was Left Trailing with  Blank Spaces.. i am converting it by using LTRIM.

Answer (score 1):

That is the correct way to convert it to an INT as long as you don't have any alpha characters or NULL values.

If you have any NULL values, use

```
ISNULL(column1, 0)
```

Comment: yes that i know for ISNULL but we dont have any Null Values there we have to Manualy conert it from Varchar to Int.

Comment: He claims the column has `NOT NULL` enforced on it.

Comment: I am using Select convert(int,'Au') but still get the conversion failure error.

Any clues?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. In most case, it is caused by the comma issue.

```
cast(replace([FIELD NAME],',','') as float)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below command, and it will ask all values to INT

select case when isnumeric(YourColumn + '.0e0') = 1 
            then cast(YourColumn as int) 
            else NULL 
       end /* case */
    from YourTable

Answer (score 0):

There are two type of convert method in SQL.

CAST and CONVERT have similar functionality. CONVERT is specific to SQL Server, and allows for a greater breadth of flexibility when converting between date and time values, fractional numbers, and monetary signifiers. CAST is the more ANSI-standard of the two functions.

**Using Convert**

```
Select convert(int,[Column1])
```

**Using Cast**

```
Select cast([Column1] as int)
```